# Error in svm prediction with two classes for prediction variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, one-hot-encoding

I want to apply the SVM classifier to my problem where the prediction vector has two classes. SVM shows an error as "bad input" when I try to input such a prediction vector. If it's possible to provide such input to SVM? If not, how to cope with this issue?

```
Y = np.zeros((len(y), max(y)+1))
for i in range(len(y)):  
Y[i, y[i]] = 1

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold    
kf = KFold(n_splits=3)
kf.get_n_splits(X)
print(kf)
KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):      
X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
classifier = SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

[Matrix Y appears as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4toCN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPu92.png)

Comment: We need to be able to see the prediction vector, can you print it out? if it is bad input then it's likely an issue with the prediction vector (either dimensions or data)

Comment: You'll have to share the error you are seeing, along with your SVM code, and what X is.

Comment: Add more information related to your question. Inpput your error information in detail.

Comment: X is a 4769*7 matrix whereas Y is a 4769*2 matrix. Error appears because Y has 2 columns. I want train SVM with this input. Here is the SVM code.                         
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

    classifier = SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state = 0)
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)